# a blank strip on right side when show a bootstrap v3 modal [duplicated]

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap v3. When I show a modal with js, it goes well but appear a blank white strip on the very right side of page. After modal hide, this strip disappears. It seems to be a problem caused by css margin-right:15px of "body.modal-open:" in bootstrap css. After I delete the whole code below, it works well. Is that ok to delete it?

```
body.modal-open,.modal-open .navbar-fixed-top,.modal-open .navbar-fixed-bottom{margin-right:15px}
```

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9855

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap modal pushes html content to the left](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337238/twitter-bootstrap-modal-pushes-html-content-to-the-left)