# Positioning footer

Tags: html, css

Due to my footer HTML tag switching places, I'm having trouble positioning it.
As you can see in my IDE I've set my footer to be at the most bottom inside the HTML section. However, once I run my app, it changes position by going 2 lines up.

Is it because of the remodal-pop box configuration? Any idea how to fix this?
Here is the image, to make it more understandable.

[image]

Here is my css-footer code:

```
.footer {
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     padding: 1rem;
     text-align: center;
     background: #2E3438;
     color:white;
     height: 23px;
     line-height: 8px;
     font-size: 13px;         
}
```

and html and body which I can NOT change due to a remodal-pop bug:[Twitter Bootstrap modal pushes html content to the left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337238/twitter-bootstrap-modal-pushes-html-content-to-the-left)

```
html {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**EDIT**  (after the given answer):
this is the code which you need to change (append to prepend) the name of the file is *jquery.remodal.js*:

```
if (!remodal.$overlay.length) {
      remodal.$overlay = $('<div>').addClass(namespace + '-overlay');
      remodal.$body.prepend(remodal.$overlay);
    }

    remodal.$bg = $('.' + namespace + '-bg');
    remodal.$closeButton = $('<a href="#"></a>').addClass(namespace + '-close');
    remodal.$wrapper = $('<div>').addClass(namespace + '-wrapper');
    remodal.$modal = $modal;
    remodal.$modal.addClass(namespace);
    remodal.$modal.css('visibility', 'visible');

    remodal.$modal.prepend(remodal.$closeButton);
    remodal.$wrapper.prepend(remodal.$modal);
    remodal.$body.prepend(remodal.$wrapper);
```

Comment: if the **.remodal-overlay** and **.remodal-wrapper** were generated. they will always appear in the bottom unless you try to make a **div** above the **.footer** and set the **remodal-overlay** and **remodal-wrapper** generate only inside the **div** that you made

Comment: Since HTML5, we use the `footer` tag. I invite you to look at it.

Comment: @html 5 footer or not, it agains stays the same

Comment: @MarkSoliver this is what I thought so, tnx for the suggestion div!

Comment: @none That was a comment... Not an answer... Anyway, have you tried in a different browser ?

Comment: is it now working sire?

Comment: I' m trying to fix it now..., will report eventually

Comment: @MarkSoliver I've tried mutliple options and it doesn't work, also tried your dive suggestion. I' m also starting a bounty...

Comment: @none Could you make an online demo using [tag:jsbin]?

Comment: Hmm. Well yes but it'll take some time...

Comment: @none use jsfiddle or codepen it is better suited.And have you tried using !important ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `remodal` js script just appends those `div`-s on document ready.

Both of them, as I can see at remodal home page are `position: fixed` so as long as you did not changed styling of those remodal containers - they couldn't shift your absolutely postioned footer.

Probably problem lies elsewhere. You can modify remodal script and prepend (or place elsewhere) those containers but I don't think that would matter.

Maybe there is problem with one of remodal styles? You could remove styles from DOM for test (leaving only js).

Comment: hah, I don't believe it after chaging all the relevant appends it works now!! Tnx man, well deserved +100. .prepends works perfeclty. I have to wait 23 hours to award you...

Comment: btw. @none - can you post exactly which `append` should be changed? I think it would help others.