# Bootstrap modal does not popup but pushes html content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Modal content displays fine when triggered by a clicking button via Ajax. However, instead of the modal popping up and making the entire page behind it grey and inactive the modal content appears within the HTML content and pushes the other contents down. I had run a similar modal on a different framework (Shiny) other than rails and it worked fine. I came across a similar question: [Twitter Bootstrap modal pushes html content to the left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337238/Twitter%20Bootstrap%20modal%20pushes%20html%20content%20to%20the%20left/23851892). The working solution was do this in CSS: `html{overflow:hidden;height:100%;}` and

```
body{overflow:auto;
  height:100%;}
```

which I tried but did not work. Other similar posts conclude that issues are due to bugs in Bootstrap and suggest to modify bootstraps source code but I suppose they were fixed since the posts date like more than 2 years ago.

My code:
/app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require d3
//= require_tree .
```

app/views/indicators/index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Add release', new_release_path,  {:remote => true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window'} %>
<div id="modal-window" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

/app/controllers/indicators_controller.rb

```
def new_release
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

app/views/indicators/new_release.js.erb

```
$("#modal-window").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'indicators/indicator_modal') %>");
$("#modal-window").modal('show');
```

/app/views/indicators/_indicator_modal.html.erb

```
<div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
   <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
   **here comes whatever you want to show!**
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
   <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
   <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
 </div>
```

Could it be a Rails specific issue? How can I make the modal pop-up?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing some markup that the modal requires ([see the Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals))

You have:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" ... >
  <div class="modal-header" ... >
  <div class="modal-body" ... >
  <div class="modal-footer" ... >
```

But you need:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" ... >
  <div class="modal-dialog" ... >
    <div class="modal-content" ... >
      <div class="modal-header" ... >
      <div class="modal-body" ... >
      <div class="modal-footer" ... >
```

Comment: It still appears the same even with the `<div class="modal-dialog" ... > <div class="modal-content"`

Comment: Do you have any custom styling on `#modal-window` that might be affecting e.g. the `display` attribute? I'd also remove the `hide` class, as `.modal` already has `display: none`.

Comment: I have commented out all my styling but getting the same result

Answer (score 0):

If your using bootstrap gem try to add following line to /app/assets/javascripts/application.js

here are the https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

```
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

or else if manually using boostrap by using source code try to add below file to javascript directory in your application

```
bootstrap/js/modal.js
```

Comment: Adding the line to the `application.js` did not solve the problem but adding the lines `@import "bootstrap-sprockets"; @import "bootstrap";` to the `.scss` file solved the problem

Comment: good, style sheets are not imported to your application.following docs is the best thing.